# Layout with 2 columns

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to create 2 columns using Linearlayout? Something similar to attached image:
[layout http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16134555/layout.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16134555/layout.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it's very easy.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <!-- child views -->
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
     <!-- child views -->
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't ` android:layout_weight="0"` to make only 2 columns.

Comment: It's just the ratio between the two. So if they are both 1 they would be the same size. If you set it to 1 and 2, you would get one third and the other 2 thirds width.

Comment: I was using this as alternative to a table layout for accomplishing the same requirement, because this approach had less code.  However, it seems the right-left alignment is very sensitive when you change the style of the any element.  Even when having all the same items, changing any outter padding or margin was causing the alignment to go off.  Additionally, the drawback I encountered in this solution is that you can't treat a row of items as one group of views under a parent (I am reusing a label/edittext layout).  I have had to go back to the table layout for the necessary flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a linear horizontal linear layout with two internal linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout />
<LinearLayout />
</LinearLayout>
```